next auth credentials async authorize(credentials)
import bcrypt from "bcrypt";
import type { NextAuthConfig } from "next-auth";
import Credentials from "next-auth/providers/credentials";
import { LoginSchema } from "@/schemas";
import { getUserByEmail } from "@/data/user";

export default {
    providers: [
        Credentials({
            async authorize(credentials) {
                const validatedFields = LoginSchema.safeParse(credentials);
                if (validatedFields.success) {
                    const {email, password} = validatedFields.data;

                    const user  = await getUserByEmail(email);
                    if (!user || !user.password) return;

                    const passwordMatch = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);
                    if (passwordMatch)  return user;
                }
                return;
            },
        }),
    ],
}satisfies NextAuthConfig

Type '(credentials: Partial<Record<string, unknown>>) => Promise<{ id: string; name: string | null; email: string | null; emailVerified: Date | null; image: string | null; password: string | null; } | undefined>' is not assignable to type '(credentials: Partial<Record<string, unknown>>, request: Request) => Awaitable<User | null>'.
Type 'Promise<{ id: string; name: string | null; email: string | null; emailVerified: Date | null; image: string | null; password: string | null; } | undefined>' is not assignable to type 'Awaitable<User | null>'.
Type 'Promise<{ id: string; name: string | null; email: string | null; emailVerified: Date | null; image: string | null; password: string | null; } | undefined>' is not assignable to type 'PromiseLike<User | null>'.
Types of property 'then' are incompatible.
Type '<TResult1 = { id: string; name: string | null; email: string | null; emailVerified: Date | null; image: string | null; password: string | null; } | undefined, TResult2 = never>(onfulfilled?: ((value: { id: string; ... 4 more ...; password: string | null; } | undefined) => TResult1 | PromiseLike<...>) | null | undefi...' is not assignable to type '<TResult1 = User | null, TResult2 = never>(onfulfilled?: ((value: User | null) => TResult1 | PromiseLike<TResult1>) | null | undefined, onrejected?: ((reason: any) => TResult2 | PromiseLike<...>) | null | undefined) => PromiseLike<...>'.
Types of parameters 'onfulfilled' and 'onfulfilled' are incompatible.
Types of parameters 'value' and 'value' are incompatible.
Type '{ id: string; name: string | null; email: string | null; emailVerified: Date | null; image: string | null; password: string | null; } | undefined' is not assignable to type 'User | null'.
Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'User | null'.
i'm facing this error while implementing the authorize function

change return; to return null

I have already tried it, still not working

As mentioned, change return; to return null and add return null after if (passwordMatch)  return user; line
